# LazyInitializationException even with OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to use OpenEntityManageInViewFilter, but I keep having the LazyInitializationException. People had similar problems when having the EntityManager initialized twice - but that seems not to be my case. In the exception log I can see, that the  Filter is correctly firing.

web.xml:

```
<web-app version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>web-application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>web-application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/web-application-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>openEntityManageInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>openEntityManageInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

web-application-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:applicationContext.xml"/>
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
        <property name="viewNames" value="*" />
        <property name="cache" value="false"/>
        <property name="prefix" value=""/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".ftl"/>
        <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="false"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="handlerAdapter" autowire="byType" class="org.maite.controller.router.HandlerAdapter" />
    <bean id="handlerMapping" autowire="byType" class="org.maite.controller.router.HandlerMapping" />
</beans>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">


    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:spring-configured/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
</beans>
```

And the exception (you can see that the OpenEntityManagerInView takes part of the stack trace):

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: org.goout.model.Event.schedule, no session or session was closed
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:147)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
root cause

org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: org.goout.model.Event.schedule, no session or session was closed
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:393)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:385)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:378)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:112)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toArray(PersistentSet.java:188)
    java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:151)
    freemarker.template.SimpleSequence.<init>(SimpleSequence.java:162)
    freemarker.template.DefaultObjectWrapper.wrap(DefaultObjectWrapper.java:117)
    freemarker.template.WrappingTemplateModel.wrap(WrappingTemplateModel.java:134)
    freemarker.template.SimpleHash.get(SimpleHash.java:224)
    freemarker.core.Dot._getAsTemplateModel(Dot.java:76)
    freemarker.core.Expression.getAsTemplateModel(Expression.java:89)
    freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:94)
    freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
    freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
    freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:310)
    freemarker.core.BlockAssignment.accept(BlockAssignment.java:83)
    freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
    freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
    freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:199)
    freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:237)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.processTemplate(FreeMarkerView.java:366)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.doRender(FreeMarkerView.java:283)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.renderMergedTemplateModel(FreeMarkerView.java:233)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractTemplateView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractTemplateView.java:167)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    org.maite.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:38)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:147)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the same problem as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003152/openentitymanagerinviewfilter-problems), which means you have 2 EntityManager beans - this is causing the confusion.

Basically you need to remove the

```
<import resource="classpath:applicationContext.xml"/>
```

from `web-application-context.ml`, partition your beans such that web-tier and application beans are in separate context files and make sure your component scan in each picks up the correct beans. This might require moving classes into different packages, difficult to advise without more information about the structure of your project.

Finally reference both contexts from web.xml

Answer (score 2):

Could you please provide your DAO class which is unable to initialize the collection of another DAO class?

Try to put these parameters in the web.xml in filter.

```
<init-param>
        <param-name>entityManagerFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>entityManagerFactory</param-value>
</init-param>
```