# still getting LazyInitializationException even after using spring OpenSessionInViewFilter

Tags: spring, hibernate, lazy-initialization

Environment:

- Netbeans 7.1
- Spring 3.1.1
- Hibernate 4.0.1
- JSF

I have implemented the Spring OpenSessionInViewFilter using org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter

However, I am still getting the error:
`org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role`

I know the filter is being called - I can see it in the stack trace.  What more do I need to configure?
Hibernate configuration includes the following:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2005Dialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</property>
<property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.SunONETransactionManagerLookup</property>
<property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory</property>
```

Comment: You likely have the problem from this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597918/lazyinitializationexception-even-withopenentitymanagerinviewfilter/9706773#9706773