# Spring Binding List<Object> to Form:checkboxes

Tags: java, spring, binding, checkbox

I can't seem to get my form to bind to the checkboxes control.  I read many posts on here and tried a few techniques but no luck.  Maybe a fresh set of eyes will help.

my controller:

```
public String editAccount(@RequestParam("id") String id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("account", accountService.getAccount(id));
    model.addAttribute("allRoles", roleService.getRoles());
    return EDIT_ACCOUNT;
}
```

my jsp:

```
<form:form action="" modelAttribute="account">
<form:checkboxes items="${allRoles}" path="roles" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id" delimiter="<br/>"/>
</form>
```

the generated html:

```
<span><input id="roles1" name="roles" type="checkbox" value="1"/><label for="roles1">User</label></span><span><br/><input id="roles2" name="roles" type="checkbox" value="2"/><label for="roles2">Admin</label></span><span><br/><input id="roles3" name="roles" type="checkbox" value="3"/><label for="roles3">SuperAdmin</label></span<input type="hidden" name="_roles" value="on"/>
```

I used a second for each loop (not shown) to make sure that the model object contained the roles.  It does, yet none of the checkboxes are checked and when I submit the roles object is always empty.  Can someone please tell me what I'm missing?

Thanks

EDIT

Sorry just realized it might be helpful to see the account and role objects:

```
public class Account {

    private String username, firstName, lastName, email;
    private List<Role> roles;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 6, max = 50)
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public List<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this);
    }

}

public class Role {

private int id;
private String name;

public Role() {}

public Role(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 50)
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

EDIT #2

Controller Post Method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateAccount(@RequestParam("id") String id, @ModelAttribute("account") @Valid AccountEditForm form, BindingResult result) {
    System.out.println("FORM VALUES AFTER: " + form);
    return (result.hasErrors() ? EDIT_ACCOUNT : ACCOUNT_REDIRECT);
}
```

AccountEditForm is the form backing object.  When I do a GET I grab an Account object and pass the values into an AccountEditForm before displaying the screen.  I will attach the AccountEditForm just for clarity.  It is very similiar to the account object.  I just happened to seperate my form objects from my model objects.

```
public class AccountEditForm {

    private String username, firstName, lastName, email;
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 6, max = 50)
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public List<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this);
    }

}
```

EDIT #3 Role Property Editor

```
public class RolePropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    private Map<Integer, Role> roleMap = new HashMap<Integer, Role>();

    public RolePropertyEditor(List<Role> roleList) {
        for (Role r : roleList) roleMap.put(r.getId(), r);
    }

    public void setAsText(String incomingId) {
        Role role = roleMap.get(incomingId);
        System.out.println("PROPERTY EDITOR ROLE " + role);
        setValue(role);
    }

    public String getAsText() {
        System.out.println("PROPERTY EDITOR ID " + ((Role)getValue()).getId());
        return String.valueOf(((Role)getValue()).getId());
    }
}
```

Defined in my controller like:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setAllowedFields(new String[] {
            "username", "password", "confirmPassword", "firstName", "lastName", "email", "acceptTerms", "currentPassword"
    });
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Role.class, new RolePropertyEditor(roleService.getRoles()));
}
```

EDIT #4 NEW ProeprtyEditor

```
public class SecurityRolePropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    private RoleService roleService;

    public SecurityRolePropertyEditor(RoleService roleService) {
        this.roleService = roleService;
    }

    public void setAsText(final String name) {
        Role role = roleService.getRoleByName(name);
        setValue(role);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an equals method to your Roles entity.

see this [answer (Spring MVC Pre Populate Checkboxes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989711/spring-mvc-pre-populate-checkboxes/6996350#6996350):  of a similar question for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I added equals to my Role object and now when I view the screen the checkboxes are populated correctly but when I make a change or do a submit, the roles property of the account object bound to the form is always empty.

Comment: @blong824 Is the problem that the Role objects are not submittet, not populated in the Account object or not saved?

Comment: I removed all the code to save and just added a print statement to the post method.  The roles object is always empty.  So not populated in the Account object.

Comment: @blong824: could you please add the post-method?

Comment: @blong824: do you have any registered PropertyEditor or converter to convert the id of an Role to its role object?

Comment: I added the property editor.  I just realized that my setAllowedFields property does not contain that field.  That might be what is causing it not to make it back to the server.

Comment: setAllowedFields has nothing to do with it.  I commented it out and same result

Comment: So I changed the List to List<String> instead of List<Role> and that works correctly.  So something is not binding with the Role object.  I'm am debugging just thought I'd give an update.

Comment: So I changed my propertyEditor to the one posted above in Edit #4.  Changed the jsp to use the name for itemValue in the checkboxes form control.  I look up the role by name instead of id which is ok since they should be unqiue.  Not sure why I couldn't get the id to work but I can live with it like this.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing implementation `equals` and `hashCode` method on your entities.