# Spring binding checkbox with Set of Objects

Tags: java, forms, jsp, spring-mvc, checkbox

I would like to build a form to save an User. I have 2 tables, User and UserRole as described in Spring Security. To save an user I need to create a User Object that contains a field Set. I want to create a list of checkboxes and map them into an Set of UserRoles, but I don't know how to map them with checkboxes. I have the following classes:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

@Autowired
IUserService userService;

/** Default GET form handler for users, in submission will call saveRegistration */
@RequestMapping(value="/createuser",  method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String createUser(Model model) {
    // User form will be bind to this User object
    model.addAttribute("user", new User()); 

    // Code about adding the user roles to JSP?
    // Maybe something like this?:
    // User u = new User ("useruser","123456",false);
    // Set<UserRole> roles = new HashSet<UserRole>();  
    // roles.add(new UserRole(u,"ROLE_ADMIN"));  
    // roles.add(new UserRole(u,"ROLE_USER"));   
    // model.addAttribute("roles", roles); 

    return "createuser";
}

/** This method will be called on form submission, handling POST request,
 * It also validates the user input */
@RequestMapping(value="/createuser", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String doCreateUser(Model model, @Valid User user,  BindingResult result) {
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return "createuser";
    }
    userService.createUser(user,user.getUserRole()) //createUser(User user, Set<UserRole> role)
    return "success";
}
}
```

My JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/createuser.css" />
</head>
<body onload='document.createUserForm.username.focus();'>


<sf:form name="createUserForm" method="post"
    action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/createuser"
    commandName="user">

    <table class="formtable">
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Username:</td>
            <td><sf:input class="control" path="username" name="username"
                    type="text" /><br />
                <div class="error">
                    <sf:errors path="username"></sf:errors>
                </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td class="label">Role:</td>

            <td>
            <ul>  
            <sf:checkboxes element="li" path="userRole" items="${roles}"></sf:checkboxes>
            </ul></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Password:</td>
            <td><sf:input class="control" path="password" name="password"
                    type="password" />
                <div class="error">
                    <sf:errors path="password"></sf:errors>
                </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Confirm Password:</td>
            <td><input class="control" name="confirmpass" type="password" />
                <div class="error">
                    <sf:errors path="password"></sf:errors>
                </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label"></td>
            <td><input class="control" value="Create account" type="submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</sf:form>
```

User Role:

```
public class UserRole {

private Integer userRoleId;
private User user;
private String role;

public UserRole () {

}

public UserRole(User user, String role) {
    this.user = user;
    this.role = role;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "user_role_id", 
    unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getUserRoleId() {
    return userRoleId;
}

public void setUserRoleId(Integer userRoleId) {
    this.userRoleId = userRoleId;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "username", nullable = false)
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

@Column(name = "role", nullable = false, length = 45)
public String getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}

public String toString () {
    return role;

}

}
```

And User:

```
public class User {


@NotNull
@NotBlank(message="Username cannot be blank.")
@Size(min=4, max=15, message="Username must be between 4 and 15 characters long.")
@Pattern(regexp="^\\w{6,}$", message="Username can only consist of numbers, letters and the underscore character.")
private String username;

@NotBlank(message="Password cannot be blank.")
@Pattern(regexp="^\\S+$", message="Password cannot contain spaces.")
@Size(min=6, message="Username must be longer than 6 characters.")
private String password;

//private String confirmPassword;


private boolean enabled;

private Set<UserRole> userRole = new HashSet<UserRole>(0);

public User() {
}

public User(String username, String password, boolean enabled) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.enabled = enabled;
}

public User(String username, String password, 
    boolean enabled, Set<UserRole> userRole) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.enabled = enabled;
    this.userRole = userRole;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "username", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 45)
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

@Column(name = "password", nullable = false, length = 60)
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@Column(name = "enabled", nullable = false)
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}

public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user")
public Set<UserRole> getUserRole() {
    return userRole;
}

public void setUserRole(Set<UserRole> userRole) {
    this.userRole = userRole;
}

/*public String getConfirmPassword() {
    return confirmPassword;
}

public void setConfirmPassword(String confirmPassword) {
    this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
}*/

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found ConverterFactory but I don't want to convert type (in this case List to Set<UserRoles>), I think there must be any mapping method in the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution using Properties Editor. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544479/spring-mvc-type-conversion-propertyeditor-or-converter) and [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html)

Answer (score 1):

Refert [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-checkbox-and-checkboxes-example/) post, and i dont see the itemlabel and itemid attribute, which maps to userrole object.

also refer [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421346/spring-binding-listobject-to-formcheckboxes)

Comment: Thanks but I saw both of them before. The first one is not useful because it only maps standard values, and the second one redirect in the end to a broken link, but maybe for someone are useful.